# I'm trying to make a simple app in flutter that fetches data from an API. However when I try running the code I get the following error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

"Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable' "

It says that the error is in the following line:

```
for(var jsonObject in jsonObjects){
    objects.add(Object.fromJson(jsonObject));
    }
```

For context, the entire code is this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<Object> _objects = [];
  Future<List<Object>> fetchData() async{
    const String urlString = 'https://api.publicapis.org/entries';
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(urlString);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    final List<Object> objects = [];
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonObjects = json.decode(response.body);
      print("Step 1");
      for(var jsonObject in jsonObjects){
        objects.add(Object.fromJson(jsonObject));
        
      }
    }
    return objects;
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902147/internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-iterabledyn). Be sure to specify the type of the list.

Comment: @nonsocchi Thanks so much for your reply! I tried specifying it as a list but now get the error - "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast"

Comment: I think what you want is this: json.decode(response.body["entries"])

Comment: So, parsing your JSON fails, but you show neither your JSON, nor your parsing code... not sure how we can be of help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that `response.body` is not a list of elements, and you are assuming it is. Instead of that, it's a "key" : "value" type of json object, which cannot be iterated.

The `for (var e in collection)` syntax is made to be used with an Iterable collection, and _InternalLinkedHashMap (and maps in general) are not iterables.

The solution is to parse the response properly. Check [this link](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-b7f991611d3e) if you want to follow best practices for flutter development json parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your api response's body is a `Map`:

```
{"count":1425,
 "entries":[
    {"API":"AdoptAPet","Description":"Resource to help get pets adopted","Auth":"apiKey","HTTPS":true,"Cors":"yes","Link":"https://www.adoptapet.com/public/apis/pet_list.html","Category":"Animals"},
    {"API":"Axolotl","Description":"Collection of axolotl pictures and facts","Auth":"","HTTPS":true,"Cors":"no","Link":"https://theaxolotlapi.netlify.app/","Category":"Animals"},
     ...
 ]
}
```

what you are looking for is a list, Try this:

```
var jsonObjects = json.decode(response.body["entries"]);
      print("Step 1");
      for(var jsonObject in jsonObjects){
        objects.add(Object.fromJson(jsonObject));
        
      }
```